# Как убрать пробелы между блоками Run внутри TextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Пример:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="("/>
   <Run Text="Text"/>
   <Run Text=")"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Ожидается:

> (Text)

Результат:

> ( Text )

Comment: Скажите - а если у вас в XAML 20 разных тэгов используется - вы будете 20 меток на вопрос вешать? :)

Comment: И да, разве TextBlock внутрь TextBlock вкладывать правильно?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вопрос касается именно работы TextBlock с вложенными тегами. Поэтому метка "TextBlock" нужна. Все теги которые можно поместить внутрь TextBlock перечислять не имеет смысла.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, философия WPF не запрещает TextBlock вкладывать внутрь TextBlock. Поэтому вопрос правильности некорректен. Но всё равно, для вас я исправил тэги на Run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если блоки Run в разметке находятся на разных строках, то происходит их разделение пробелом друг от друга.

Происходит это потому, что символ переноса строки внутри TextBlock преобразуется в пробел.

Решением проблемы становится их размещение в одну строку:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="("/><Run Text="Text"/><Run Text=")"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Или:

```
<TextBlock>
   (<Run Text="Text"/>)
</TextBlock>
```

Результат в обоих случаях будет без пробелов:

> (Text)

Comment: @VladD, во втором случае будет без пробелов, я проверял. Можете попробовать.

Comment: Хм, и правда. Простите, ошибся.

Comment: @VladD, бывает... спасибо, что попробовали. ;)